# wordpress wp menu in home page and inner page

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-nav-menu-item

My main wp_nav_menu is called header-menu
and that menu like this

- Home
- About
- Insight

  - Test 1
  - Test 1
- About 2

  - Test
  - Test

I want to call this menu in home page without showing sub items . That can i do using

```
             <?php   
             wp_nav_menu( array(
             'menu_class'     => 'main-nav navbar-nav ml-auto',
             'container' => false,
             'theme_location' => 'header-menu',
             'depth' => 1,
            ) );
            ?>
```

But after when i go to the Insight page i want to show secondary main menu and secondary menu (only test1 and test2) How can i do this

Answer (score 0):

Create a new menu and conditionally call in home page , that would be easy solution

Comment: Ok, Then what about the secondary menu? how do i call the secondary menu ?

Comment: <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'container' => false, 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav responsive-nav main-nav-list navbar-left')); ?>